# Context path conflict with Spring UrlTag in webapp-runner?

Tags: java, spring, heroku

We have a Java/Spring app deployed into Heroku, using the excellent `webapp-runner` as the Tomcat-lite servlet container. In upgrading from 7.0.27.1 to 7.0.31.1, it seems the behavior for setting a default context path of "/" causes problems with `<spring:url>` tags. Specifically, with the default context path of "/", tags like `<spring:url value="/foo/bar"/>` end up getting rendered as `//foo/bar`. All browsers I tested on OS X (Chrome, Safari, Firefox), for example, don't seem to handle those particularly gracefully, and try to load `http://foo/bar`, resulting in all kinds of chaos.

I can think of two workarounds:

- Specify `--context-path ""` argument to `webapp-runner` - this seems "best" since it corresponds to the 7.0.27.1 behavior
- Write the tags as `<spring:url context="" .../>` - unsure what additional consequences there might be, considering how `SpringUrl` uses leading slash to determine `UrlType`.

Are either of these reasonable? If not, is there some other solution I should consider?

Comment: Is your App working on a local Tomcat or is this also happening on your local Machine?

Comment: App works in Tomcat running in STS/Eclipse on local machine, but not when running in "Heroku emulation" - e.g., via `foreman start`. Stepping through, I've verified that, when run in STS/Eclipse, `request.getContextPath()` returns "". When run in foreman/webapp-runner, it comes through as "/". Spring UrlTag pre-pends the value, resulting in `//foo/bar`.

Comment: Also, note that with webapp-runner 7.0.27.1, context path was also "" by default. The "/" default got added in a later release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

webapp-runner-7.0.34.1 has changed the default `--context-path` back to `""`. If you upgrade, it should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue of **double slash //** and upgrading from webapp-runner 7.0.34.0 to **webapp-runner 7.0.34.1 solved the problem for me**.

I had tried with both `<spring:url>` and `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`. Upgrading webapp-runner solved the problem in both cases.

More details: http://bit.ly/1zuL1T1